# Laravel4 NotFoundHttpException in Wamp Server

Tags: laravel-4, wampserver

I am  reading Laravel4 quick start tutorial

[Laravel4 quick start](http://laravel.com/docs/quick#routing)

I have installed laravel4  on Wamp server in Windows . I was able to access home page which says **"you have arrived".**

Later in ther router.php I have added only one router as per quick start guide, but for some I am getting this error.

[image]

**Error:**

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

---

**Router.php**

```
   Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});

Route::get('/users', function() //this one i hav added
{
    die;
    return 'Users!';
});
```

**config.php**

```
 'debug' => true,



'url' => 'http://localhost:99',


'timezone' => 'UTC',


'locale' => 'en',
```

Comment: Make sure mod_rewrite is enabled in your WAMP setup. This article looks like a good explanation on [how to turn on mod_rewrite](http://blog.cmstutorials.org/tutorials/tips-tricks/how-to-make-mod_rewrite-work-on-wamp).

Comment: Have you setup your site as a sub-domain? Like `localhost/subdomain`? If so add `RewriteBase /subdomain` in `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not prefix the route with a slash. Use `users` rather than `/users`.

Comment: I did that, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem today and it took a while to resolve it, but here's how I did it. In this example I created a WAMP Apache Alias 'lava', so `http://localhost/lava/` took me to the "You have arrived" page successfully. However even trying a really basic route of:

```
Route::get('test', function()
{
    return "hello?!";
});
```

Would give me the `NotFoundHttpException` errors the same as you. To get routing working I did this:

1. Ensure mod_rewrite is enabled (WAMP does it by default, but double-check)
2. Ensure open_ssl is enabled (easy to do via the WAMP tray icon)
3. Edit `app/config/app.php` and set the url to match your alias, so in my case:

   `'url' => 'http://localhost/lava/',`
4. Edit `public\.htaccess` - you can use the one the QuickStart recommends, but you need to change it in 2 places:

```

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /lava/

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /lava/$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

```

In the above I've added the RewriteBase line which matches the alias, and also added the alias in the RewriteRule regexp.

The above for me works fine (Windows 7, WAMP) although the .htaccess file is no use when deployed to a live server that doesn't use the same alias.

Answer (score -1):

Trying going to index.php/users. If this loads then you need to setup url rewriting in the htaccess file.